# Differential Equations, unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just had a quick question regarding the uniqueness of the general solution of first-order differential equations:

For $x'(t)=Ax(t)$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. and initial condition $x(0)=x_0$, the unique solution is $x(t)=e^{tA}x_0$.

The proof for showing that the solution is unique involves differentiating the matrix product $e^{-tA}x(t)$.

Could someone please explain why we always multiply by $e^{-tA}$.

Many thanks,
Best.

Comment: Do you mean $x(0) = x_0$, $x(t) = (e^{t}A)x_0$, etc. for the equations you give?

Comment: Your solution formula should be $e^{tA}x_0$, `$e^{tA}x_0$`. Is this a typo or part of your question?

Comment: Hi yes, that is the solution. I just wasn't sure why we always multiply by (e^tA). Just to be clear, this isn't (e^t)A.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the method of the integrating factor. In general for $x'=A(t)x+b(t)$, if you have a solution for the matrix equation $F'(t)=A(t)F(t)$, $F(0)=I_n$, also  called the fundamental solution, you can, a la variation of constants, set $x(t)=F(t)u(t)$ and either differentiate $u(t)=F(t)^{-1}x(t)$ to 
\begin{align}
u'(t)&=-F(t)^{-1}F'(t)F(t)^{-1}x(t)+F(t)^{-1}x'(t)
\\
&=-F(t)^{-1}A(t)x(t)+F(t)^{-1}(A(t)x+b(t))
\\
&=F(t)^{-1}b(t)
\end{align}
or in the variation of constants fashion compute
\begin{align}
x'&=F'u+Fu'=AFu+Fu'
\\
&=Ax+b
\\\\
\implies
Fu'&=b
\end{align}

---

For a linear system with constant matrix, $x'(t)=Ax(t)+b(t)$, the fundamental matrix is the matrix expontential $F(t)=e^{tA}$ with derivative $F'(t)=AF(t)=F(t)A$.