# $u(t)=e^{At} u_0$ is solution of the IVP $u'(t)=Au(t)$ and $u(0)=u_{0}$.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

If A is a given matrix n order matrix and $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$
. Then $u(t) = e^{tA}u_0$ solves the initial value system of ODE $u'(t) = Au(t)$ with $u(0) = u_0$ in $(0,\infty)$. Prove the converse as well.

To show $u(t) = e^{tA}u_0$ is solution of given system is not difficult. But for converse part I am not sure what to do.

Either to show this has unique solution in $(0, \infty)$ then it follows that any solution coincides with $u(t) = e^{tA}u_0$ by uniqueness and we are done.

Is my reasoning correct ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: A common “trick” is to show that if $u$ is a solution then $e^{-tA} u(t)$ is constant.

Comment: @MartinR Great trick, thanks.

Comment: I strongly assume that this has been asked and answered before. My favourite math search engine [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) is currently offline, therefore I cannot check it.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks it's a nice search engine, seeing it the first time. Ya, using your favorite search engine I found it. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289205/differential-equations-unique-solution?noredirect=1

Comment: An additional remark: $\{e^{tA}\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a one-parameter semigroup of bounded linear operators generated by the matrix (i.e. bounded linear operator $A$). This is a more abstract framework but see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226363792_One-Parameter_Semigroups_for_Linear_Evolution_Equations) (chapter 1 at least) if you are interested in how your problem fits into a more general context.